# Jasmine not recognizing spied on method called from asynchronous function resolution

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, asynchronous, jasmine

From my controller, upon instantiation, I am calling an asynchronous method that calls a scope method:

```
app.controller 'MyCtrl', ($scope,mySvc) ->
  ## do some initial stuff
  mySvc.asyncMethod
  .then (an_array) ->
    val = $scope.myScopedMethod
```

My test is like so:

```
describe "my tests", () ->
  $controller = undefined
  $scope = undefined
  $q = undefined
  createController = undefined
  mySvc = undefined

  beforeEach inject ($controller, $rootScope, $q, _mySvc_) ->
    $scope = $rootScope.$new()
    mySvc = _mySvc_
    deferred = $q.defer()
    deferred.resolve []
    spyOn(mySvc,'asyncMethod').and.returnValue deferred.promise
    spyOn($scope, 'myScopedMethod').and.callThrough()
    createController = () ->
      return $controller('MyCtrl', {$scope: $scope, mySvc: mySvc})

  # this assertion works
  it "should call asyncMethod", () ->
    controller = createController()
    expect(mySvc.asyncMethod).toHaveBeenCalled()

  # this also works
  it "should define myScopedMethod", () ->
    controller = createController()
    expect(angular.isFunction($scope.myScopedMethod)).toBe true

  # this fails with 'Error: Expected a spy, but got Function.'
  it "should call $scope.myScopedMethod", () ->
    controller = createController()
    $scope.$digest()
    expect($scope.myScopedMethod).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

I get the same error whether I call `$digest()` or not. I am expecting `$digest()` to resolve `asyncMethod` so that it calls `myScopedMethod`, but something is not right.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `$scope.myScopedMethod` does not yet exist when you try to create the spy for it.

You need to create the spy after the function is created.  Hopefully it is created as part of the controller initialization, so you could maybe do this:

```
beforeEach inject ($controller, $rootScope, $q, _mySvc_) ->
    $scope = $rootScope.$new()
    mySvc = _mySvc_
    deferred = $q.defer()
    deferred.resolve []
    spyOn(mySvc,'asyncMethod').and.returnValue deferred.promise
    createController = () ->
        ctrl= $controller('MyCtrl', {$scope: $scope, mySvc: mySvc})
        spyOn($scope, 'myScopedMethod').and.callThrough()
        return ctrl
```

Answer (score 0):

scope is not a spy

spy is created using

```
var spy = spyOn($scope, 'myScopedMethod')
```

and than

```
expect($scope.myScopedMethod)
```